# How to get a element's position which in a UserControl

Tags: wpf

I have a UserControl:

```
<UserControl d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="200" ...>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Ellipse Name="leftEllipse" Grid.Column="0" Width="50" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Fill="Red" />
        <Ellipse Name="rightEllipse" Grid.Column="1" Width="50" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Fill="Green" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Here is my MainWindow:

```
<Window ...>
    <Canvas Name="canvas1">
        <my:MyUserControl x:Name="myUserControl1" Width="200" Height="100" Canvas.Top="100" Canvas.Left="100" />
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

I know how to get the position of myUserControl1 :

```
double x = Canvas.GetLeft(myUserControl1);
```

But can anyone tell me how to get the position of myUserControl1.leftEllipse?
And when myUserControl1 apply a RotateTransform, the myUserControl1.leftEllipse's position will changed, won't it?

Comment: In WPF, you usually don't manage the controls' locations and sizes, this is done automatically by the layout system. What are you **actually** trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to know the coordinate position of some of its parts in order to  calculate their distance from another point dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without making the generated leftEllipse field public, you could add a method to the UserControl that returns a transform object from the Ellipse's coordinates to that of an ancestor element, e.g.

```
public GeneralTransform LeftEllipseTransform(UIElement e)
{
    return leftEllipse.TransformToAncestor(e);
}
```

You may then call it in your MainWindow like this:

```
var p = myUserControl1.LeftEllipseTransform(this).Transform(new Point());
```

---

Instead of TransformToAncestor (or TransformToVisual) you may also use TranslatePoint.

```
public Point GetLeftEllipsePosition(Point p, UIElement e)
{
    return leftEllipse.TranslatePoint(p, e);
}
```

In MainWindow:

```
var p = myUserControl1.GetLeftEllipsePosition(new Point(), this);
```

Or for the center of the Ellipse (instead of its upper left corner):

```
var p = myUserControl1.GetLeftEllipsePosition(new Point(25, 25), this);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I tried both of your methods. All of them work well! You have done me a big favor. Thank you again.